# Función espejo a DISTINCT de MySQL pero en Array() de JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Tengo el siguiente array de objetos:

```
var arr = 
[
    {
        "TokenID":"1",
        "USR":"Andrey Homez",
        "mensaje":"Hi :)",
        "date":"2017-01-17 02:52:52"
    },
    {
        "TokenID":"2",
        "USR":"Andrey Homez",
        "mensaje":"Hey!",
        "date":"2017-01-17 02:53:22"
    },
    {
        "TokenID":"1",
        "USR":"Paola Gonzales",
        "mensaje":"Hola!",
        "date":"2017-01-17 02:52:52"
    }
]
```

Quisiera que retorne un array limpio de valores repetidos, en este caso es **TokenID**, que repite el valor **1** .

Entonces, la siguiente Array() debería ser el resultado.

```
arr =
[
    {
        "TokenID":"1",
        "USR":"Andrey Homez",
        "mensaje":"Hi :)",
        "date":"2017-01-17 02:52:52"
    },
    {
        "TokenID":"2",
        "USR":"Andrey Homez",
        "mensaje":"Hey!",
        "date":"2017-01-17 02:53:22"
    }
]
```

Algo así como

```
function distinct(array,indice){
}
```

Donde `indice` es el que se va a analizar y revisar en `array` para saber si hay un valor repetido, entonces sería:

```
distinct(arr,"TokenID");
```

No considero buena idea hacer un `sort()`. El punto (objetivo) es que tenga el orden originalmente asignado.

¿De qué forma puedo hacerlo?

Comment: "No está claro lo que se pregunta", bien, ya estás feliz con tu reporte a mi pregunta, ahora argumenta por qué?

Comment: Imagino que tu pregunta está marcada como tal porque no hay un código desde el que partir... Puedes compartir lo que ya tienes hecho?

Comment: Si no está claro lo que se pregunta, entonces cómo si pudieron responder mi pregunta? Sean lógicos. Y como siempre he dicho, desde que arranca el primer reporte, todos lo siguen como corderitos a reportar por la misma razón y a veces sin leer por qué. Bye bye kids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer en esa función es:

1. Definir dos arrays vacíos:

   - Uno para los índices que ya se han encontrado
   - y otro con los objetos no duplicados
2. Recorrer todos los elementos del array y si el índice del objeto no está en el array de índices:

   - Añadir el objeto al array de objetos no duplicados
   - Añadir el índice al array de índices ya encontrados
3. Devolver el array de objetos no duplicados

El código sería algo como esto:

```
function distintos(arr, indice) {

  // variables auxiliares
  var indices = [];       // array con los índices ya usados
  var resultado = [];     // array con los objetos no duplicados

  // atravesamos el array original 
  for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    // si el índice no se ha encontrado previamente
    if (indices.indexOf( arr[x][indice] ) < 0) {
      // añadir ese objeto al array de resultados
      resultado.push( arr[x] );
      // añadir ese índice al array de índices encontrados
      indices.push( arr[x][indice] );
    }
  }

  // devolvemos los resultados
  return resultado;
}
```

Aquí dejo un ejemplo funcionando:

```js
var datos = [
  {
    "TokenID":"1",
    "USR":"Andrey Homez",
    "mensaje":"Hi :)",
    "date":"2017-01-17 02:52:52"
  },
  {
    "TokenID":"2",
    "USR":"Andrey Homez",
    "mensaje":"Hey!",
    "date":"2017-01-17 02:53:22"
  },
  {
    "TokenID":"1",
    "USR":"Paola Gonzales",
    "mensaje":"Hola!",
    "date":"2017-01-17 02:52:52"
  }
];

function distintos(arr, indice) {
  var indices = [];
  var resultado = [];

  for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    if (indices.indexOf( arr[x][indice] ) < 0) {
      resultado.push( arr[x] );
      indices.push( arr[x][indice] );
    }
  }
  
  return resultado;
}

console.log("ANTES DE ELIMINAR DUPLICADOS");
console.log(JSON.stringify(datos));

datos = distintos(datos, "TokenID");

console.log("DESPUES DE ELIMINAR DUPLICADOS");
console.log(JSON.stringify(datos));
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, si al array retornado quisiera que viniera ordenado por **date**. Es posible? Es que cuenta mucho la fecha en la que fueron enviados, de forma ascendente. Claro.

Comment: En ese caso, podrías hacer un `sort` con una función propia de comparación antes de devolver el resultado

Comment: Hasta el momento tu respuesta es la más acertada, si encuentro incompatibilidades con el navegador debo buscar otra respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

Usando la función [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) puedes mantener o eliminar elementos de un arreglo, el cual nos servirá para nuestra función. En la función de retorno de *.filter*, nos dice la documentación que si retorna **true**  mantiene el elemento, o **false** de otra manera.

**función distinct()**: 
Crea una variable temporal, que guardará valores únicos para posteriormente verificar si ya existen, de otro modo mantenerlos en el  arreglo.

```js
var arr = 
[
 {
  "TokenID":"1",
  "USR":"Andrey Homez",
  "mensaje":"Hi :)",
  "date":"2017-01-17 02:52:52"
 },
 {
  "TokenID":"2",
  "USR":"Andrey Homez",
  "mensaje":"Hey!",
  "date":"2017-01-17 02:53:22"
 },
 {
  "TokenID":"1",
  "USR":"Paola Gonzales",
  "mensaje":"Hola!",
  "date":"2017-01-17 02:52:52"
 }
];

function distinct(array,indice){
  var uniques = []; //temporal
  return array.filter(function(item){
    //indexOf buscará el valor, si no existe retornará true, por lo cual se mantendrá en el arreglo 
    //false en caso el valor ya exista en la variable uniques
    return uniques.indexOf(item[indice]) < 0 ? uniques.push(item[indice]) : false
  })
}

console.log("By TokenID:", distinct(arr, "TokenID"));
console.log("By USR:", distinct(arr, "USR"));
console.log("By date:", distinct(arr, "date"));
```

Comment: Creo que Internet Explorer 8 no soporta nativamente la funcion **filter** :/

Comment: Personalmente, deberías empezar a usar estas funciones, si te fijas, en tan solo 3 lìneas se ha conseguido lo esperado, IE siempre ha sido un problema, y siempre ha habido soluciones para este navegador. En la propia documentación de Mozilla podrás encontrar el [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter), que te permitirá soportar `.filter()` en cualquier navegador. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener los valores sin repetir podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Recorrer el arreglo de objectos
- Crear un `hash` donde guardamos los valores que ya fueron encontrados
- Si el valor no fue encontrado aún (eg, no esta en el `hash`) lo agregamos en un nuevo arreglo.

Por ejemplo, así:

```js
function unique(array, prop) {
  var uniques = [],
      hash = {};
  
  array.forEach(function(object) {
    var value = object[prop];
    
    if (!hash[value]) {
        hash[value] = true;
        uniques.push(object);
    }
  });
  
  return uniques;
}

///

var arr = [{
  "TokenID":"1",
  "USR":"Andrey Homez",
  "mensaje":"Hi :)",
  "date":"2017-01-17 02:52:52"
}, {
  "TokenID":"2",
  "USR":"Andrey Homez",
  "mensaje":"Hey!",
  "date":"2017-01-17 02:53:22"
},{
  "TokenID":"1",
  "USR":"Paola Gonzales",
  "mensaje":"Hola!",
  "date":"2017-01-17 02:52:52"
}];

console.log(unique(arr, 'TokenID'));
```